# Will I be able to make schedule with firebase cloud

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a website with two simple button ON and OFF that change LED_STATUS to "ON" or "OFF" in realtime database and I would like to develop it by adding schedule to set for example Monday 17.00-17.30 and at this time I want the LED_STATUS:"ON" and my question is will I be able to do this with firebase cloud ?